# Trigger Jenkins job on checkin

Tags: jenkins, perforce, jenkins-plugins, p4v

My Source Code management tool is Perforce and Auto-Deployment of the latest build is done using Jenkins. Whenever a new QA build comes-in, two folders would be updated within 2 minutes of each other - namely folder `VersionNumber` and folder `AppFiles` which hold the VersionNumber and the Files required for deployment respectively.
I continuously poll for changes at the folders VersionNumber and AppFiles  in order to deploy the build immediately as shown below:

```
//depot/AppFiles/... //AutoDeployment/depot/AppFiles/...
//depot/VersionNumber/... //AutoDeployment/depot/VersionNumber/...
```

What happens is Jenkins runs the job twice as there are two checkins in Perfoce one for `VersionNumber` and another one for `AppFiles` one after the other. I actually want Jenkins to run the job only after it has Synced both the files as without the other file, the Auto-Deployment will fail. 
Is this possible

Comment: I came across 'Quiet Period' feature in Jenkins. So if I set my Quiet period to 5 minutes, would that work for me

Comment: Is one always checked in after the other?  If so, could you only monitor that one and then sync the other in your build script?